# Problems with storyboard colors in mixed objective-c/swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, colors, xcode-storyboard

I added a new view controller to my objective-c project.  The new view controller is written in Swift.  Everything compiles correctly and functions correctly except that no matter what color I choose for the view's background color, it either comes out white (default) or black.  If I decrease the alpha for the default background color it just gets gray.  If I have anything over about 0.4 alpha for any other color the view is black.

Second problem:  the code in my Swift view controller to set background color for the view appears to have no effect.  Relevant code is below. I first set the view background color to white with alpha 1.0 and then change it to the color I want.  None of this has any effect. Is this because it has already been set in the storyboard? If so, how can I override the storyboard settings programmatically?  I am very new to Swift but have been programming objective-c for about one year and I haven't seen this kind of problem in a pure objective-c project.  Xcode version is 7.3.

I would really appreciate any help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.username.delegate = self;
    self.password.delegate = self;

    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0x255/255, alpha: 1.0)


    //set the background color to blue-green
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(
        red: 0x00/255,
        green: 0x7d/255,
        blue: 0x96/255,
        alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these problems are due to auto layout problems.  If there are any autolayout issues (even if they are not flagged by a red arrow in the project navigator), the storyboard produces a black screen. I'm not sure why this happens with Swift: objective-C would just produce a screen with some layout problems. Once all the autolayout issues get fixed (usually by using Reset to Suggested Constraints), there isn't a black screen.  Also, my code for setting the screen background color then works.This was very frustrating and I don't know why it works this way when the code underlying the view is Swift and not objective-C. But if there is the tiniest variation in the storyboard scene that has a tiny autolayout problem, I get a black screen.